# Get string not sending variables correctly

Tags: php, ajax, get

At least I assume that it my problem here^ Basically, its really simple, im sending an ajax made get string to a php script, however the string is not being broken down correctly apparently.

Ajax snippet:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxQuery.php?name="+str+"&identifier="+id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

PHP

```
//variables sent from Ajax
$owner = $_GET['name'];
$identifier = $_GET['identifier'];
```

For some reason `$_GET['identifier']` is empty. a `print_r($_GET)` shows me:

```
Array
(
[name] => John Doeidentifier=1
)
```

The name is `John Doe` and the `id` is 1, but for some reason they are not splitting up, and as far as i am aware, my Get string is compiled correctly any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you uri encode your variables that you are inserting into the ajax request.

Comment: use &amp; thats only I can predict

Comment: It looks like you have `"ajaxQuery.php?name="+str+"identifier="+id` instead of `"ajaxQuery.php?name="+str+"&identifier="+id` in your actual code

Comment: @FAngel the & is there...

Comment: Does everything come back under `$_REQUEST['name']`?  And do you see the & in the value?  Otherwise fail to understand the 'not splitting up'.

Comment: @Akam tried it, no dice

Comment: can you show your code again if possible

Comment: @Akam  `xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxQuery.php?name="+str+"&amp;identifier="+id,true);`  i tried it with and without the semi colon

Comment: use this: "ajaxQuery.php?identifier=" + id + "&amp;name="+ str + ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its likely the url is broken due to the space in one of the strings. To fix this, what you need to do is encode each variable so that spaces and other special characters get handled correctly

`xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxQuery.php?name="+encodeURIComponent(str)+"&identifier="+encodeURIComponent(id),true);`

Comment: I tried implementing your suggustion, but nothing changed. what exactly does encodeURIComponent do, sorry new-ish to ajax

Comment: It encodes strings into a format that is uri compatible. For example, spaces are replaced with %20. Other characters that might break uri parsing are also replaced with similar codes.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, basically it is the equivalent of `htmlentities`? Also, this did solve my problem, for some reason it required i refresh my index page, which realistically shouldnt have been needed, due to the fact that everything is located exernally... but thanks

Comment: Similar, but the encoding used is different. Entities would encode an ampersand (&) as &amp; while url encoding would convert it to %26. PHP has `urlencode` and `urldecode`.